# Is there a "simplified" view of code in the Assistant Code Editor in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working my way through the Apple iBooks title "App Development with Swift." On page 86, it says to open the Assistant Editor to make a connection to an interface element. In the accompanying image, the editor shows a nice, neat, compact snippet of code, about a dozen lines long.

[image]

However, when I open the editor in my follow-along project, the same UIViewController file shows me about 600 lines of code. The steps I'm taking to get here are Open Xcode, select New Single-view iOS Project, select Main.storyboard, select the ViewController object in the outline, and open the assistant editor.

Is there a setting somewhere to show a simplified version of the code? Or has the code for the ViewController changed that much since the book was released? Or did they maybe just create a super-simple version of the editor for the images in the book?

I'd like to be able to follow along with what they're doing in the book, but at this point I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Click on 'Automatic' above the source editor and select the view controller.

[image]

Comment: When I do that, nothing changes. FWIW, the file listed is not ViewController.swift. It’s UIViewController.h. I assume that’s significant?

Comment: @Andy Yes, that's significant. You need to get ViewController there. How to you open the assistant editor?

Comment: I’m clicking the three little lines menu at the top right of the main storyboard view and then selecting Assistant. I closed Xcode and started over, though, and now everything looks as it should. No idea what the issue was but I’m sure it was user error.

Comment: @Andy I'm sure it wasn't a user error. Xcode has many bugs. If things like this happen, always try to restart Xcode. If this this doesn't help, clean and delete the Derived Data folder.